# Node aws-sdk s3 file upload sizes

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

When using the aws-sdk npm plugin for nods.js, I can upload a pdf on 50kb with the following code (to AWS s3):

```
var params = {
            Bucket: BUCKET, 
            Key: pdf_key, 
            Body: file,
            ContentType: 'application/pdf'
        };
        var s3 = new AWS.S3();

        s3.putObject(params, function(error, data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(error);
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                callback(error, null);
            } else {
                callback(null, pdf_key);
            }
        });
```

But when uploading a 11mb pdf, even with specifying the `ContentLength`, the upload just continues forever, even with a timeout of 2 minutes.

The question is how do I make aws s3 accept the large pdf file?

**UPDATE**

I have still not found any documentation or anwers for the question.

**UPDATE 2**

I will accept answers which show's this or another framework that can do this. I will need that framework to be able to also allow auth-read of the object.

**UPDATE 3**
I got it working for now but I haven't found a reason it shouldn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think it's a code problem. Uploading to S3 is usually slow and network fluctuations can make it even more unpredictable. If you are worried about uploading big files you could use multipart uploads. Here is an example: https://gist.github.com/sevastos/5804803

Comment: Well, the multipart upload sounds nice but is that really necessary? Largest PDF is ~50mb I can accept an answer if you write that it's generally slow etc etc, because I've got it working now without any modifications from my jobs internet, which is quicker than my homes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Connecting to S3 isn't fast and then depending on the network fluctuations you can get timeouts and other weird behaviors.

The code you provided is fine, but you could take advantage of multipart uploads that could solve problems especially with >5MB files.

I made [a rough implementation of a multipart upload](https://gist.github.com/sevastos/5804803) and also made it to retry the upload of any failing part up to 3 times, this will also work for smaller files than 5MB.

Comment: Thanks, I will stay with my own code for now but I know where to look if the problem reappears. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I am trying to upload ~60 Mb file without multipart. Strangely it works alright in my dev env, from my local machine. But it throws error from my production env hosted on AWS . Error : "(node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral."

Comment: Could you give me an example of what it would look like if you want to stream a file directly from a URL to s3. I want the buffer to read the file directly from the URL without downloading it first but I can't make it work.