# Node.js AWS S3 [RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using node.js v0.10.32 on ubuntu 14.04.1 and trying and use aws-sdk(2.0.18) to upload (and download) a file from S3. But the following error shows up when uploading a large file, say 32MB.

```
(node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.
...
(node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I tried to make stack size larger with `node --stack-size=16384 ...` but no luck.
Here is my uploader source code:

```
if (process.argv.length < 7) {
    console.log ("usage: " + process.argv [0] + " " + process.argv[1] + " <config> <region> <bucket> <key> <file>")
    return -1
}

var config = process.argv[2]
var region = process.argv[3]
var bucketName = process.argv[4]
var key = process.argv[5]
var file = process.argv[6]

var fs = require ('fs')
var aws = require ('aws-sdk')
fs.readFile (config, "utf8", function (err, configFile) {
    if (err) {
        console.log ("Config file cannot be read: ", err)
        return -1
    }
    aws.config = JSON.parse (configFile)
    aws.config.region = region

    var bucket = new aws.S3 ({params: {Bucket: bucketName}})

    fs.readFile (file, function (err, fileData) {
        if (err) {
            console.log ("Cannot open file for uploading: ", err);
        } else {
            bucket.createBucket (function () {
                var data = {Key: key, Body: fileData}
                bucket.putObject (data, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log ("Error uploading data: ", err);
                    } else {
                        console.log ("Successfully uploaded!");
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    })
})
```

I am no idea now, please help.
Maybe aws's multipart upload is the solution for uploading large files?

Comment: You might make your voice heard on [this issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/158). Also, for uploading files you might try something like [`s3-upload-stream`](https://github.com/nathanpeck/s3-upload-stream), that way you don't have to load the entire file into memory to upload it.

Answer (score 0):

Though I couldn't find out why the stack size exceeds maximum, I found out the cause of it.

The problem is S3 is not fast and network instability makes situation even worse.
This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126908/node-aws-sdk-s3-file-upload-sizes).

One way to solve this is to make use of multipart upload with retry mechanism ([sample code](https://gist.github.com/sevastos/5804803), can be found in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126908/node-aws-sdk-s3-file-upload-sizes)).